# Can't set environment variables for container in ApplicationLoadBalancedFargateService

Tags: python-3.x, aws-cdk

(CDK 1.18.0 and Python 3.6)

```
task_role = iam.Role(
    self,
    id=f"...",
    assumed_by=iam.ServicePrincipal("ecs-tasks.amazonaws.com"),
    managed_policies=[...]
)

repo = get_repo(self)

task_def = ecs.FargateTaskDefinition(
    self,
    "...",
    memory_limit_mib=30720,
    cpu=4096,
    task_role=task_role,
    execution_role=self.ecs_execution_role,
)

cont = task_def.add_container(
    "...",
    image=ecs.ContainerImage.from_ecr_repository(repo),
    logging=ecs.LogDrivers.aws_logs(stream_prefix=f"Logging"),
    command=["bash", "start.sh"],
    environment={"NAME1": 'VALUE1', "NAME2": 'VALUE2'} # what would I have to put here?
)

cont.add_port_mappings(ecs.PortMapping(container_port=8080))
fg = ecsp.ApplicationLoadBalancedFargateService(
    self,
    "...",
    task_definition=task_def,
    assign_public_ip=True,
)
```

I want to pass NAME1=VALUE1 and NAME2=VALUE2 to the container.

I tried various ways to express the environment variables. But none worked. Am I doing something fundamentally wrong here?

Other than this specific issue the service deploys and runs.

Comment: does "nothing works" mean the variables are not available inside the task definition? or does it fail to deploy?

Comment: "none worked" refers to trying various schemas for the env variables like `{"n1":"v1","n2":"v2"} or [{"n1":"v1"},{"n2":"v2"}] or [{"name":"n1","value":"v2"},{"name":"n2","value":"v2"}]`. 

It neither `deploy`s nor `synth`s. The CF template for the stack in cdk.out/ doesn't contain the env variables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The approach you follow seems to work here on the latest version (1.23.0). But I could not find any hint in the release notes why this might have changed. Can you update to the latest version?

```
        task_def.add_container("container", environment={"a": "b", "c": "d"},  image=aws_ecs.ContainerImage.from_registry(name="TestImage"), memory_limit_mib=512)
```

```
  newtask1C300F30:
    Type: AWS::ECS::TaskDefinition
    Properties:
      ContainerDefinitions:
        - Environment:
            - Name: a
              Value: b
            - Name: c
              Value: d
          Essential: true
          Image: TestImage
          Memory: 512
          Name: container
```

Comment: I already confirmed with a colleague that the approach is correct and works for CDK 1.18.0 using `Dict[str,str]` - maybe there is something wrong with my CDK setup.